# My cat keeps peeing on my stairs!

Tags: cats, toilet-training

[image: Russian Blue Cat]
**Please respond to this question**
My cat keeps peeing on the bottom of our staircase. I *think* I've figured out what started it: we brought home another cat, after one of our cats ran away, and he started peeing all over.
He occasionally pees in the basement whenever the basement door is open.
:
We've tried having two litter boxes, changing the litter, having only one litter box, changing his food, and we even got rid of our other cat and started over again!
He doesn't have any health issues, he's strictly indoors (Completely by his choice. He hates the outdoors.), the only pet in the house, age 13 in SHY (Standard Human Years), gets attention anytime somebody's home, a Russian Blue breed.
:
I don't know what to do!

#### **Help!**

Comment: Have you taken him to the vet to rule out a health issue?

Comment: Yes, but they've found nothing wrong with him.

Comment: How have you cleaned the places he's gone? How old is he? Has he been declawed? Have you tried locking him in a bathroom with a box for a day or two?

Comment: I marked your question as a duplicate for now, but please come back and edit the answers to these questions into your post so we can help you. There are just too many possibilities without this information.

Comment: Are litter boxes covered? Tried moving the litter boxes elsewhere in the house? Is he neutered? I'm assuming your vet obtained a sample of his urine for urinalysis? Is his stool normal in appearance - sometimes inappropriate urination can be caused by bad associations with the litter box due to constiption, etc.

Comment: The litter boxes are _not_ covered. Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes, his stools are fine.

Comment: This ain't no copy, Zaralynda!